# Rvest and xpath returns misleading information

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I am struggling with some scraping issues, using rvest and xpath.

The objective is to scrape the following page

https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/BT*0/futures-prices

and to extract the names of the futures

BTF21
BTG21
BTH21
etc for the full list of names.

The xpath for those variables seem to be xpath='//a'.

The following code provides no information of relevance, thus my query

```
  library(rvest)
  url <- 'https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/BT*0'


  valuation_col <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//a')

  value <- valuation_col %>% html_text()
```

Any hint to proceed further to get the information would be much needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Web scraping 101: Did you check the HTML source code of the website that these elements are actually in there? (No, the DOM view in the browser's developer tools is not the HTML source code. Use "view source" from the context menu.)

Comment: Thanks for the response and, above all, for the patience as I am a newcomer to scraping. I checked the console, and it seems there is a GET to this website https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?fields=symbol%2CcontractSymbol%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CopenPrice%2ChighPrice%2ClowPrice%2CpreviousPrice%2Cvolume%2CopenInterest%2CtradeTime%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType%2ChasOptions&list=futures.contractInRoot&root=BT&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.type%2Cfield.description&hasOptions=true&page=1&limit=100&raw=1

The link seems to provide most information, but how to go from there?

Comment: So the website uses Ajax to load the information it displays. If you look at the request in the browser's developer tools, you can see that the response is in Ajax format, which is actually a good thing because it's much easier to consume JSON than to scrape numbers off of an HTML page. But if you try to repeat the Ajax request outside of the context of the parent page, you will get a "401 Unauthorized" response from the server, instead of actual data. I suspect this has to do with cookies and request headers.

Comment: So your task is to figure out a way to make this request so that the server won't reject you. The simplest scraping/hot-link protection is checking the `Referrer` header, so try to re-issue the request with a `Referrer` set to `"https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/BT*0/futures-prices"`. Might already do the trick. If it doesn't, they also check Cookies and other headers, which makes it more complex. This is a game of trial and error, you have to emulate the behavior of a "real" browser well enough for the server to give you the wanted file.

Comment: So yeah, there is a chance to get that data, but not though web scraping. You should concentrate on getting that Ajax request to work from your code. I have no idea how to do that in R, though.

Comment: Well, beyond my reach...

Comment: Not really. The `httr` package seems to be suitable, have a look at [their quickstart guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html). It can do simple requests, you can set headers, you even can use sessions and cookies and all that, if that's really necessary. Start simple and work your way forward. You can see in the browser that it can be done and you can look at all the values the browser sends.